# What kind of plug is this?

Tags: electrical-engineering

Can anyone help me to identify this electrical connector set?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

- Hint: One male plug style connector has some text saying "HC 0617 CANNON"

Comment: Do you know what this cable is used for?

Comment: I would call that 5 pin DIN...

Comment: As @SolarMike states it looks like a [DIN connector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DIN_connector).

Answer (score 1):

Cannon is a manufacturer of electrical connectors used in the audio engineering and scientific instrumentation fields. This Cannon connector looks like an instrumentation cable. Contact CANNON on the web for more info.

Answer (score 0):

The look like professional-grade DIN or XLR connectors, with screw locking threads.

Cannon is a specialist connector manufacturer - now part of the ITT conglomerate.

They were probably originally used for professional audio cabling.

Answer (score 0):

It seems balanced XLR stereo connection with screw lock. In pro audio cabling balanced means each side (left or right of the stereo) will be carried on three wires, positive, negative, ground.

In receiver positive or negative which carry the same signal with different polarity will be flipped and coupled with the other one, chocking noise picked by the cable on its way, because once flipped the noise wave will be the mirror image of self. 
This has 5 connectors. one seems to be ground two for each right and left.